# Text alignment on multirow when it breaks between pages

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, multirow

How can I get properly displayed text on multirow cells, when they break between pages?

Here the example http://web-engineering.com.ua/mtest.pdf

Text '/importp' on the end of first page prints  unproperly.

I don't know on which cell page will be broken.

here code

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|l|l|X|}

\hline\noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}\endhead
\noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}\hline\endfoot

\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{pagemode=bookmark|thumb|none} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{nameddest=<name>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{highlight=<lt>,<rt>,<top>,<btm>} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{fullscreen=yes|no} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{usept=yes|no} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If \textbf{yes}, then all values for positioning such as \textit{top, left, right, btm, wd, ht,} etc. are absolute and measured in points(1/72 inch). 

    Otherwise these values will be interpreted as a  count of pixels at 100\% zoom. This behavior is default for Adobe  Acrobat/Reader. In this case, to receive absolute value in points,  Acrobat calculates it by:

    V(pt)=V(from\_cmd)\(\ast{}\)72.0/(disp\_resol)

    The  \textit{disp\_resol} parameter is used in global ‘Preferences/Page  Display/Resolution’ location (both in Acrobat and PDF-XChange Viewer).} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\texttt{PDFXCview.exe /A "page=10\&zoom=200,250,100" mypdffile.pdf}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/close}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{When this command is used, viewer will close files specified by arguments <filename1>{\dots}<filenameN>. If any of these files was modified, behavior of the viewer depends of command parameter (\textbf{save}, \textbf{discard} or \textbf{ask}). If \textbf{save} parameter was used, documents which should be closed will be saved. If \textbf{discard} was used – all modifications will be lost. And with \textbf{ask} argument, viewer will ask what to do.

    If all files opened into the viewer will be closed by /close command, application will be closed too.

    \textbf{For  example,}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /close c:\textbackslash mydocument.pdf}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /close:save c:\textbackslash mydocument.pdf}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\multirow{6}{0.13\newtblsparewidth}{\textbf{/print}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{When this command is specified, PDF file(s) specified by parameters <filename1>{\dots}<filenameN> will be printed. Printing parameters differ depending on arguments used:} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{default=yes|no} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If this argument is used and its value is \textbf{yes}, viewer will reset printing settings before printing documents. Otherwise if the last is used, stored parameters will be applied. Default value: \textbf{yes}.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{showui=yes|no} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Defines if printing progress will be shown. Default value: \textbf{no}.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{printer=<printername>} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Specifies the printer on which documents should be printed. If not specified, default system printer will be used. Please note, if printer name contains spaces or \textbf{\&} character, it should be enclosed into quotes.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{pages=<pagesrange>} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Specifies the pages range(s) which should be printed. Syntax  of range is the same as on print dialog. If argument is omitted, all  pages will be printed.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\textbf{For  example,}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /print:showui=yes c:\textbackslash mydocument.pdf}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/printto}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Almost  the same command as \textbf{/print}, but destination printer should be  specified not as command argument, but as command line parameter  followed by \textbf{/printto} command.

    \textbf{For example,}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /printto "Raster-XChange" c:\textbackslash mydocument.pdf}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/exportp}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{This command exports current viewer’s settings into the file specified by setting\_file\_name parameter.} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\multirow{3}{0.13\newtblsparewidth}{\textbf{/importp}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{This  command imports viewer’s settings from the file specified by  setting\_file\_name parameter. Please note, all your current settings will  be overridden and lost.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{web=yes|no} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If  this argument is used and its value is \textbf{yes}, then imported  settings will be stored into browser-plugins registry location at exit  of the application.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\textbf{For  example,}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /importp c:\textbackslash mysettings.dat}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /import:web=yes c:\textbackslash mysettings.dat}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{filename1, filename2, {\dots} filenameN}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{PDF  file name(s) which should be opened, closed or printed. Please note, if  filename contains spaces, it should be enclosed into quotes ("")} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/RegServer, /UnregServer}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Special commands used for registering and unregistering viewer’s COM interfaces.} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\multirow{3}{0.13\newtblsparewidth}{\textbf{/makeassoc}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Makes PDF-XChange Viewer as default PDF-viewer.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{web=yes|no} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If  this argument is used and its value is \textbf{yes}, it enables displaying  PDF in Internet browsers by PDF-XChange Viewer.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\textbf{For  example,}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /makeassoc}

    \texttt{PDFXCView.exe /makeassoc:web=yes}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/makeiassoc}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Enables displaying PDF in Internet Browsers by PDF-XChange Viewer.} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/storeassoc}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Stores existing PDF-associated application (if it is not PDF-XChange Viewer) that can be restored in the future.} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/restoreassoc}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Restores a previously stored PDF-associated application.} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\textbf{/usep}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{Opens  the viewer with the settings from the file specified by  <settings\_filename> parameter.  \textbf{For  example,}

    \textbf{relative paths:}

    \texttt{settings.dat}

    \texttt{mysettings.dat}

    \texttt{MyFolder\textbackslash settings.dat}

    \textbf{full paths:}

    \texttt{"c:\textbackslash PDF-XChange Viewer Settings\textbackslash settings.dat"}

    \texttt{"\textbackslash \%UserProfile\%\textbackslash PDF-XChange Viewer Settings\textbackslash settings.dat"}

    \texttt{"c:\textbackslash  Documents and Settings\textbackslash \%UserName\%\textbackslash PDF-XChange Viewer Settings\textbackslash settings.dat"}

    \textbf{Note:}  If there are no settings (or they are incorrect, or they cannot be  found under the given name), viewer will be opened with the default  ones. While shutting down, viewer will try to save the current settings  to the given direction. If the settings could not be saved, an error  message will be shown.} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.13\newtblsparewidth}}{\multirow{10}{0.13\newtblsparewidth}{\textbf{/runjs}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\textbf{command scheme:}

    \texttt{/runjs[:[newinst[=<yes|no>]][\&showui[=<yes|no>]][\&minui[=<yes|no>]][\&log=[=<yes|no>]]]  <scriptfilename> <filename> [<filename2>{\dots}  <filenameN>]}} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\textbf{options:}} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{newinst=<yes|no>} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If  this argument is used and its value is \textbf{yes}, then application  process will be started for executing this command. If this option is  not specified or its value means \textbf{no}, then the application process  can be used for executing this command.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{showui=<yes|no>} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If  specified without any value or value means \textbf{yes}, then the  application is displayed with UI. Otherwise this command will be  executed without UI.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{minui=<yes|no>} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If  \textbf{showui} have been specified before and this option is specified  without any value or the value means \textbf{yes}, then the application  displays minimized UI (like a tab in the task bar).} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth}}{log=<yes|no>} & \multicolumn{2}{|m{0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{If  specified without any value or the value \textbf{means} yes, then the  application creates a log of executing of this command. The log file  "\_RunJSLog.txt" will be placed to our program folder.} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|m{0.35\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.15\newtblsparewidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+0.37\newtblsparewidth}|}{\textbf{parameters:}} \\ \cline{2-4} 
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With difficulty....

probably the easiest (if you don't insist that your multirow text is vertically centered,, which appears to be the case) is to make sure that the multirow text is within the first (say) three spanned rows) and then use `\\*` rather than `\\` to suppress line breaking on those rows.